# Need to change from rows to column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

i have a table like

```
id,Jdate,Desc
1,3-jul,a
2,3-jul,b
3,3-jul,c
1,4-jul,a
2,4-jul,b
```

query:

```
SELECT jdate,id_1,desc_1,id_2,desc_2,id_3,desc_3
from
(select jdate,id,
'id'+ CAST (row_number() OVER(PARTIOTION BY jdate order by jdate) AS varchar(5))AS id_seq,
desc,
'desc' + CAST (row_number() OVER(PARTIOTION BY jdate order by jdate) AS varchar(5))AS id_seq
FROM temp)temp
PIVOT
(MAX(lotid)
FOR id_seq IN(id_1,id_2,id_3)
)PIV;
```

i need output as

```
jdate,id_1,desc_1,id_2,desc_2,id_3,desc_3
3-jul,1,a,2,b,3,c
4-jul,1,a,2,b
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: I am using oracle. Unable to edit it

Comment: `'id' + CAST (row_number() ....) ` is invalid for Oracle. In Oracle (and standard SQL) the string concatenation operator is `||` - `+` is for numbers

Comment: Using below query right now:                                                                                         SELECT jdate,id_1,desc_1,id_2,desc_2,id_3,desc_3
from
(select jdate,id,
'id_' ||TO_CHAR (row_number() OVER(PARTIOTION BY jdate order by jdate) )AS id_seq,
desc,
'desc_' || TO_CHAR (row_number() OVER(PARTIOTION BY jdate order by jdate))AS id_seq
FROM temp)temp
PIVOT
(MAX(lotid)
FOR id_seq IN(id_1,id_2,id_3)
)PIV;

Comment: But this is giving error

Comment: `PARTIOTION` is that spelt correctly ?

Comment: there no lotid in query not in temp table you mentioned above.

Comment: its PARTITION only just type error here and its not lotid its id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach to get desired output is through below query

```
with abc as 
(SELECT jdate, LISTAGG(id||','||desc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS list_1 
FROM   test_table
GROUP BY jdate) 
select abc.jdate, regexp_substr(list_1,'[^,]+',1,1)  id_1 ,
                  regexp_substr(list_1,'[^,]+',1,2) desc_1, 
                  regexp_substr(list_1,'[^,]+',1,3) id_2,
                  regexp_substr(list_1,'[^,]+',1,4) desc_2,
                  regexp_substr(list_1,'[^,]+',1,5) id_3,
                  regexp_substr(list_1,'[^,]+',1,6) desc_3
from abc
```

OR

if you are looking for only data output then you can use below

```
    select     'Jdate'||','||'id_1'||','||'desc_1'||','||'id_2'||','||'desc_2'||','||'id_3'||','|| 'desc_3'  DATA from dual
    union
    SELECT jdate||','|| LISTAGG(id||','||desc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) as DATA FROM   test_table GROUP BY jdate
   order by data desc
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: what if we want to make it dynamic

Comment: As the number of rows /data may increase or decrease, creating dynamic column names would not be possible by only sql query. This would need PL/SQL block.